# emacs org capture mode not creating link with "%a"?

Tags: org-mode, emacsclient, org-capture

my org capture template is

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(
        ("i" "Idea" entry (file+datetree "~/Dropbox/org_mode/ideas.org")
         "* %?\n Idea: %U\n  %i\n  Link: %a")
      )
```

This template is creating:

[image]

Note: my emacs version is 26.1 on debian

Comment: Have you stored a link (using `org-store-link`) prior to invoking this capture?

Comment: yes, I tried that. I did this manually to test, do I have to write code to in configs to make sure `org-store-link` is called during capture? can you please point me to example configs that will work @NickD

Comment: Normally you don't need to call `org-store-link` manually and %a will expand to a link to wherever the cursor was when you called `org-capture`. Can you give an example of where your calling the capture from and where you want the link to point?